# ES6 Modules referencing each other results in undefined

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, module

I'm getting an error saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined

I think it has to do with my modules referencing each other, I'm not sure how to address this properly.

ListConfig.js:

```
import listConfig; from "./list.config";

const deploy = {
  lists: {
    create: async () => {
      listConfig.map();
    }
  },
  fields: {
    define: params => {}
  }
};

export default deploy;
```

Deploy.js:

```
import deploy from "./sp.deploy";

const listConfig = {
    lists: [
        {
            deploy.fields.define()
        }]
}

export default listConfig;
```

App.js:

```
import deploy from "./../../build/sp.deploy";
```

Comment: Sounds like you didn't import `deploy` from the right directory

Comment: I don't think so, I believe webpack would have caught that error before compiling. I get this error in the browser.

Comment: @Batman can you post your `webpack.config.js` ? .and post the code that invokes `fields` method..

Comment: Hey it's okay, I just moved the fields function into the list config file. I think it should be there anyways the more i think about it. So I don't have to import deploy into ListConfig.